# “The,” “a” or no article: “See you in _____ court.”

Tags: articles, nouns

Why is an article not used before the noun in sentences such as the one below?

> See you in (*the, a*) court.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Generally, you use a **zero article** with abstract nouns:

> I fell in love. (not **a** or **the** love)

In your example, **court** is being used as an abstract noun representing the legal system and its activities in general.  Note the difference between **court** (zero article) and **courtroom** (article):

> The judge is **in the courtroom** this morning.  (Specifies her location, but not her activity - maybe she's just sitting there catching up on paperwork.)
>
> The judge is **in court** this morning.  (Specifies that she is actively presiding over one or more legal procedures.)

Likewise, you can create the same distinction with your example:

> See you **in the courtroom**.

This says that there's a place (the courtroom) where we will both be in the future, but does not specify what we will be doing: we could be involved in the trial or in the jury or even just spectators.

> See you **in court**.

This says that we will be directly involved in a legal trial, usually as opposing parties on either side (although a judge might also say this to one of the litigants), and we will go through the process of holding the trial.

---

A few people have pointed out in the comments that you can use articles in front of what seem to be abstract nouns. This tends to be used when you are narrowing down the meaning to one specific instance of that abstraction.  On another site, a frequent ELL contributor (FumbleFingers) [wrote this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/use-or-non-use-of-articles-before-abstract-nouns):

> [using] **the** focusses on a *specific* instance of something, whereas **a** implies *one among many possibilities*.

Examples:

> **The** court ruled in favor of the defense. (one *specific* court)
>
> To continue, we need access to **a** court of law. (one among many possibilities)
>
> See you in court. (not specifically one instance; just the general abstract concept of formal legal proceedings and maybe I'm willing to drag you from venue to venue and through multiple appeals)

Or to use abstract noun "argument", which was raised in the comments:

> This is not relevant to **the** argument. (the *specific* on we're having)
>
> They were having **an** argument. (one argument at a particular time)
>
> We can resolve this through argument. (the abstract concept of adversarial discussion, not necessarily confined to one single discussion)

---

And as a digression, you do see "the/a court" for other definitions of the noun **court** where it is a definite location.  When speaking about a **tennis court**, for example, you could hear someone say:

> See you **on the court** [to play a match of tennis].

Comment: I'm not convinced that this use without an article with institutions is the same as the use for abstract nouns; but otherwise a good exposition. Note that in British English: "hospital" comes in that category: we would only say "in the hospital" if we were emphasising the particular hospital. This is not the case in American English (or Canadian?)

Comment: @ColinFine - I think that using the institution without an article adds on the abstract concept of "being involved in the institution's primary purpose."  Unless I'm wrong (I'm not native Canadian and the usage still isn't natural to me), even with the **in hospital** usage, you have "He's sick and **in hospital**," versus "She manages the janitorial department **in a hospital**."  The former includes the abstraction of health care provided in a medical center; the latter is a concrete place that is a medical center.

Comment: I don't think "abstract noun" is the right concept here at all. The abstract nouns "possibility", "argument", and "idea", for example, are all regularly used with "a" and "the". For that matter, the same is true of "court"; we say "The court ruled that [...]" (not \*"Court ruled that [...]"), "Sometimes a case can be appealed to a higher court" (not \*"to higher court"), etc., which are no less abstract than "in court".

Comment: "To continue, we need access to **a** court of law" "This will be handled in **the** court of law" Of law seems to modify the word enough that articles are desirable.

Comment: @ruakh : A frequent contributor to ELL noted [in another forum](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104023/use-or-non-use-of-articles-before-abstract-nouns) that you can use articles in front of abstract nouns in some cases. Quoting: "[using] **the** focusses on a *specific* instance of something, whereas **a** implies *one among many possibilities*. I can add to my answer.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: FumbleFingers' answer there is correct, but doesn't justify your claims at all! (The problem may be that you've misunderstood the term "[abstract noun](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract+noun)".)

Comment: For the first half of my life or so, I lived exclusively in places with either 0 or 1 nearby hospital, and people who went to the hospital clearly had one place to go, and the article was always used.  For the second half of my life, I've lived almost exclusively in places with 2 or more hospitals within a reasonable distance, and articles are sometimes left off of statements of people being in patient.  Many of the people I know who always use the article around here only consider one of the hospitals worth going to (according to their explicit assertion.)

Comment: @ruakh I fail to see how court is any more or less abstract than the abstract nouns FumbleFingers was talking about.  For what it's worth, my ex wife is a lawyer, so I've heard far more about court, the court, and a court than I ever expected before I got involved with her, and the usage has always been consistent with what Canadian Yankee indicated.

Comment: @EdGrimm: I think you've misunderstood my comments somehow. *Court* is indeed an abstract noun, and I'm not suggesting otherwise. But that doesn't mean that everything about the word is due to that fact. (Imagine that this answer had claimed "Generally, you use a zero article with nouns". That would obviously be wrong, right? Even though *court* is a noun? Well, the current version -- "Generally, you use a zero article with abstract nouns" -- has the same problem: yes, *court* is an abstract noun, but no, that's not why "in court" lacks an article!)

Comment: @ruakh You are correct, I did.  Rereading your comment several times over, I see it is full of possibility.  For the sake of argument, though, consider if there were common usages of those other abstract nouns you mentioned where they are in fact used without articles, and whether the distinction between when they're used without articles and with is the same.  I would suggest that the case is that those other abstract nouns are more frequently used in less abstract cases.

Comment: How about "town"? "I'm going into town this afternoon". I think it means the same with or without a definite article. Maybe that's because most people live in a situation where there is an obvious choice which town to go to.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, *court* is being used to convey a concept (justice) rather than the building of the court.  When using a noun as a concept, the article is often omitted, but not always.

This is analogous to 'going to church', 'going to school' and a host of other nouns. When saying "I'm going to church" you're implying that you're going to pray.  The actual building isn't important.  On the other hand, if you're going to *a* church to pick up some paperwork, you would generally say 'going to *the* church'.

With a hospital, I believe 'going to hospital' is said in the UK, whereas we say 'going to *the* hospital' in the U.S.  However, even is the US, we would say 'he's going into surgery'.  Going into *the* surgery would imply going for some purpose other than surgery.

It is interesting that we say 'going to church', 'going to synagogue' but I've never heard 'going to mosque'.

Comment: This answer is much better than the other (+1), but it suffers from the same problem to a lesser extent. (Note that you can't say "I'm going to church" if you're just going to your bedroom to pray alone before bed!)

Comment: In the US, we wouldn't say "going into the surgery," because (unlike in the UK) there is no place called a surgery in the US.