# Give feedback or give a feedback?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I see "Give us a feedback" sometimes in software written by non-native English speakers and it sounds wrong to me, I think the article should not be there. Am I right? Perhaps for the same reason as in [“The,” “a” or no article: “See you in _____ court.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193700/the-a-or-no-article-see-you-in-court)?

Comment: This is different - "feedback" is generally a normal mass noun (not a count noun). So you would say "Give us feedback" for the same reason that you'd say "Give us water."  This is different from the "court" example because "court" is a count noun (you can have one court or many courts).

Comment: @CanadianYankee Ah, yes, makes sense, thanks. Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Feedback is a mass noun, also known as an uncountable noun, and as such it doesn't require an article at all - and shouldn't take an indefinite article in any case. Sometimes it will want a definite article, but that would be the exception rather than the norm.